# Can't play FLV with SMPlayer

Tags: smplayer

What happens is the video plays for 10seconds exactly and then it's automatically stopped, every single time, it happens only for flv videos. If I use another player like windows media it plays fine so the problem is with SMPlayer, how to fix it?

Comment: Do you install ubuntu-restricted-extras package ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your file manager and click to *view hidden folders*.
2. Go to directory `/home/YoUrUsErNaMe/.config` and delete the folder named `smplayer`.

   **BEWARE**: *This folder you are deleting is your smplayer settings! if you want you can move this folder in somewhere safe so you can use it again later.*
3. We gonna *remove* the smplayer and will gonna install the latest version plus mplayer2. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mplayer2 smplayer
   ```